# How are attribute names with underscore managed in Pydantic Models?

Tags: python, pydantic

Can anyone explain how Pydantic manages attribute names with an underscore?

In Pydantic models, there is a weird behavior related to attribute naming when using the underscore. That behavior does not occur in python classes. The test results show some allegedly "unexpected" errors.

The following code is catching some errors for simple class and instance operations:

```py
class PydanticClass(BaseModel):
    a: int = "AAA"
    _z: int = "_Z_Z_Z"

    @classmethod
    def get_a(cls):
        return cls.a

    @classmethod
    def get_z(cls):
        return cls._z

class NonPydanticClass:
    a: int = "AAA"
    _z: int = "_Z_Z_Z"

    @classmethod
    def get_a(cls):
        return cls.a

    @classmethod
    def get_z(cls):
        return cls._z

print ("PYDANTIC MODEL CLASS TEST:")
pydantic_instance = PydanticClass()

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{pydantic_instance.get_a()}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "1 pydantic_instance.get_a()", "Accessing non-underscored attributes names in a class method", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{pydantic_instance.get_z()}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "2 pydantic_instance.get_z()", "Accessing underscored attributes names in a class method", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{PydanticClass.a}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "3 PydanticClass.a ","Accessing non-underscored attribute names as a 'static attribute'", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{PydanticClass._z}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "4 PydanticClass._z","Accessing underscored attributes names as a 'static attribute'", msg2))

print ("\nNON PYDANTIC CLASS TEST:")
nom_pydantic_instance = NonPydanticClass()

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{nom_pydantic_instance.get_a()}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "1 class_instance.get_a()", "Accessing non-underscored attributes names in a class method", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{nom_pydantic_instance.get_z()}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "2 class_instance.get_z()", "Accessing underscored attributes names in a class method", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{NonPydanticClass.a}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "3 PydanticClass.a ","Accessing non-underscored attribute names as a 'static attribute'", msg2))

try:    msg1, msg2 = "SUCCESS", f"{NonPydanticClass._z}"
except Exception as e: msg1, msg2 = "ERROR", f"{e}"
print('{0:<7} :: {1:<27} :: {2:<65} :: {3}'.format(msg1, "4 PydanticClass._z","Accessing underscored attributes names as a 'static attribute'", msg2))
```

Here are the results:

```
PYDANTIC MODEL CLASS TEST:
ERROR   :: 1 pydantic_instance.get_a() :: Accessing non-underscored attributes names in a class method      :: type object 'PydanticClass' has no attribute 'a'
SUCCESS :: 2 pydantic_instance.get_z() :: Accessing underscored attributes names in a class method          :: _Z_Z_Z
ERROR   :: 3 PydanticClass.a           :: Accessing non-underscored attribute names as a 'static attribute' :: type object 'PydanticClass' has no attribute 'a'
SUCCESS :: 4 PydanticClass._z          :: Accessing underscored attributes names as a 'static attribute'    :: _Z_Z_Z

NON PYDANTIC CLASS TEST:
SUCCESS :: 1 class_instance.get_a()    :: Accessing non-underscored attributes names in a class method      :: AAA
SUCCESS :: 2 class_instance.get_z()    :: Accessing underscored attributes names in a class method          :: _Z_Z_Z
SUCCESS :: 3 PydanticClass.a           :: Accessing non-underscored attribute names as a 'static attribute' :: AAA
SUCCESS :: 4 PydanticClass._z          :: Accessing underscored attributes names as a 'static attribute'    :: _Z_Z_Z
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is weird that Pydantic catches errors?

Comment: The weird thing is `why` is generating those errors. Which is the explanation for that behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This different treatment of underscored variables is actually explicitly documented in the section "[Automatically excluded attributes](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes)", although it is not worded clearly enough and could be better explained in my humble opinion.

---

**UPDATE (2023-08-16)**: In fairness, the [Pydantic v2 docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#private-model-attributes) do a better job by explicitly stating that they are *not treated as fields*. See below for more on what that means.

---

One crucial thing to understand about why Pydantic models treat their namespace differently than "regular" Python classes is that by default Pydantic constructs a **field** for every name declared in its namespace. A Pydantic field is a special construct that behaves differently than regular class/instance attributes would **by design**.

A field can *only* be written to and read from on **instances** of a model.

Even though you can "assign a value" in the class namespace definition, under the hood that is treated as **defining a default value** for that field and the value is *not* retained as a class attribute (unlike with regular classes). This is done by the meta class ([source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.6/pydantic/main.py#L185)) of `BaseModel`, whenever you subclass it:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int = "foo"
    _b: int = "spam"


pprint(dict(Model.__dict__))
print(f"{hasattr(Model, 'a')=}")
print(f"{hasattr(Model, '_b')=}")
```

Output (reduced) for Pydantic v1:

```
{# ...
 '__annotations__': {'_b': <class 'int'>, 'a': <class 'int'>},
 # ...
 '__fields__': {'a': ModelField(name='a', type=int, required=False, default='foo')},
 # ...
 '_b': 'spam'}
hasattr(Model, 'a')=False
hasattr(Model, '_b')=True
```

As you can see by checking the class' [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48), once the subclass is fully constructed, there is no attribute `a` left on `Model`, which is why you get an error, when you try to do get it via `Model.a` (or inside a classmethod via `cls.a`, which is equivalent). Instead it has a **field** `a` that can be accessed from **instances** of `Model` and that field will receive the value `"foo"`, unless another value is passed to the constructor.

**Underscored** names inside a model's definition are an exception to this behavior.

Let me quote:

> Class variables which begin with an underscore [...] will be automatically excluded from the model.

What *"excluded from the model"* means is that underscored names are actually treated like "normal" class attributes by Pydantic v1 models. Meaning if you assign a value to them in the definition, you can later access that from the class directly. But they do not get all the special bells and whistles that **fields** get. They are just plain old attributes.

And while those attributes can be **read** from both the class *and* an instance of that class, they **can not** be re-assigned on an instance (neither from the outside nor in an instance method) in Pydantic v1:

```py
# Pydantic v1

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    _b: str = "spam"


obj = Model()
print(obj._b)  # spam
try:
    obj._b = "eggs"
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))  # ValueError('"Model" object has no field "_b"')
```

The reason for that is that Pydantic v1 models also have a custom [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) implementation, which by default raises a `ValueError`, if you try to assign to a non-field ([source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.6/pydantic/main.py#L356)).

If you need underscored (protected) attributes for *instances* of your model, in Pydantic v1 you need to [define them accordingly](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#private-model-attributes), using either `PrivateAttr` or the `Config` setting to make underscored attributes private by default:

```py
# Pydantic v1

from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr


class Model(BaseModel):
    _b: str = PrivateAttr("spam")


obj = Model()
print(obj._b)  # spam
obj._b = "eggs"
print(obj._b)  # eggs
```

This behavior may seem weird, when you first notice it, if you assume fields behave like regular class/instance attributes, but you get used to it, once you understand that this different behavior is necessary to enable all the magic that Pydantic models provide.

---

**UPDATE**: With Pydantic **v2** this is no longer necessary because all single-underscored attributes are automatically converted to "private attributes" and can be set as you would expect with normal classes:

```py
# Pydantic v2

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    _b: str = "spam"


obj = Model()
print(obj._b)  # spam
obj._b = "eggs"
print(obj._b)  # eggs
```

This is arguably a less confusing, more consistent approach now. But the distinction between regular fields and private attributes is still present and important in v2.

Comment: Was searching around on this topic as a I needed to make a model class a singleton for an API, and discovered that if the class that inherits from `BaseModel` also inherits a class (one that does not inherit from `BaseModel`), which contains a class attribute with a leading underscore, it is *not* automatically cast to a `ModelPrivateAttr` type. 1/2

Comment: This is ideal for the singleton case, where a class attribute may define the instance you wish to return. If implementing any of the meta-dunders, then trying to return `cls._instance` would return a `ModelPrivateAttr` which would not be representative of the desired type of the variable (i.e. `_instance: Optional["MyType"] = PrivateAttr(default=None)`). 2/2

Answer (score 0):

- Attributes names without underscore correspond to instance attributes
  They are accessible from the Instance but not from the Class.
- Attributes names with underscore correspond to class attributes. They
  are accessible from both the class and the instance.

For example:

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):

    a: str = "Instance Default Value"
    _x: str = "Class original value"

    @classmethod
    def echo_cls(cls):
        "Only class attributes"
        return f"_x: {cls._x}"

    def echo(self):
        "Class and Instance attributes"
        return f"a: {self.a} / _x: {self._x}"

    c1 = MyModel()
    print("Original instances values")
    print("   c1", c1.echo())

    c1.a = "c1 Instance Attribute Changed"
    print("After changing c1")
    print("   c1", c1.echo())

    MyModel._x = "Class atrribute Changed"
    print("After changing c1")
    print("   c1", c1.echo())
```

The result is:

```
Original instances values
   c1 a: Instance Default Value / _x: Class original value
After changing c1
   c1 a: c1 Instance Attribute Changed / _x: Class original value
After changing c1
   c1 a: c1 Instance Attribute Changed / _x: Class attribute Changed
```