# Is there a way to use private fields to validation in pydantic

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I want to set one field, which cannot be in response model in abstract method. I set this field to private. I want to use this field to validate other public field.

```
class BaseAsset(BaseModel, ABC):
    amount: int
    precision: int
    nai: str
    _nai_pattern: str = None
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        object.__setattr__(self, '_nai_pattern', self.set_nai_pattern())
    
    @abstractmethod
    def set_nai_pattern(self):
        pass

    @validator('nai')
    def check_nai_format(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if v != values['_nai_pattern']:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return v

    class Config:
        underscore_attrs_are_private = True


class AssetHive(BaseAsset):
    def set_nai_pattern(self):
        return "@@000000021"
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain what your **actual** goal here is? Do you actually need that field to be private or do you just not want it to be excluded from serialization/dumping? Because the latter can be achieved without the field being private. (For details about undescored/private fields see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712642).)

Comment: No i don’t need that field private. I want to exclude this field from serialization. Three child classes must have their own nai_pattern, which i must use to validate nai field. In child classes i wanted just to implement abstract method which set new nai_pattern. The rest fields must stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach.

- Make `nai_pattern` a regular (not private) field, but **exclude** it from dumping by setting [`exclude=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#model-and-field-level-include-and-exclude) in its `Field` constructor. In addition, hook into [`schema_extra`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#schema-customization) of the model `Config` to remove the field from the schema as well.
- Make the method to get the `nai_pattern` a class method, so that it can be called from inside a validator. Then define a [`always=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#validate-always) field validator for `nai_pattern` that checks if the value is `None` and if so, calls the method to get the value.
- Write your validator for `nai` as you did before, but make sure that the `nai` field itself is defined **after** `nai_pattern` because that will ensure the `nai` validator is called after that of `nai_pattern` and you will be guaranteed to have a value to check against. ([*"Validation is done in the order fields are defined."*](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/))

Here is my suggested code:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator

class BaseAsset(BaseModel, ABC):
    amount: int
    precision: int
    nai_pattern: Optional[str] = Field(default=None, exclude=True)
    nai: str

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def get_nai_pattern(cls) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @validator("nai_pattern", always=True)
    def set_nai_pattern(cls, v: Optional[str]) -> str:
        if v is None:
            return cls.get_nai_pattern()
        return v

    @validator("nai")
    def check_nai(cls, v: str, values: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        nai_pattern = values.get("nai_pattern")
        if v != nai_pattern:
            raise ValueError(f"{v} does not match {nai_pattern=}")
        return v

    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            del schema["properties"]["nai_pattern"]
```

Demo:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError


class Foo(BaseAsset):
    @classmethod
    def get_nai_pattern(cls) -> str:
        return "abc"


print(Foo.schema_json(indent=4))

foo = Foo(amount=1, precision=2, nai="abc")
print(foo.json(indent=4))
try:
    Foo(amount=1, precision=2, nai="xyz")
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "title": "Foo",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "amount": {
            "title": "Amount",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "precision": {
            "title": "Precision",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "nai": {
            "title": "Nai",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "amount",
        "precision",
        "nai"
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "amount": 1,
    "precision": 2,
    "nai": "abc"
}
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "nai"
        ],
        "msg": "xyz does not match nai_pattern='abc'",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```