# Custom init with validation for pydantic.BaseModel's child class for private attributes

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I want to create a class that has custom `__init__` function after which validator is called. For this I tried using `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, but it doesn't help when I use "_" for private attributes.

Here's an example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, model_validator

c2b = {
    "work week": 1,
    "weekend": 2,
}


class MyClass(BaseModel):

    _a: int
    _b: int

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def validator(self) -> None:

        if self._a <= 0:
            raise ValidationError("a must be positive.")

    def __init__(self, a: int, c: str) -> None:

        super().__init__(
            _a=a,
            _b=c2b[c],
        )

MyClass(1, "weekend")
```

It triggers an error: AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_a'

But if I change `_a` to `a` and `_b` to `b` everything works fine. Is there a way to use the following structure and keep variables private?

Comment: Why not perform the validation of the private variables in `__init__`?

Comment: @AxelDonath I see two problems at this point. To begin with, validation doesn't work because the private attribute isn't defined and error "AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_a'" remains if I try to call `self._a`.

Comment: The second is that I just want to be able to raise ValidationError, which, as I remember, worked inside validators only. (I might be mistaking here, but I remember it this way).

Comment: Validating private fields seems a bit of an anti pattern when using Pydantic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985476/is-there-a-way-to-use-private-fields-to-validation-in-pydantic for a similar question.

Comment: Thank you, @AxelDonath! I'll stil leave this question open to see whether there're other interesting solutions, but it solved my problem.