# Pydantic root validator unable to access class attributes

Tags: python, pydantic

Here's a minimal example:

```
class BaseClass(BaseModel):
    description: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def initialize(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        print(cls.description) 
        # also tried print(values.get("description"), which is None
        return values


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    description = "foo"
```

Throws error
`type object 'SubClass' has no attribute 'description'", "errorType": "AttributeError`

I need to do some validation based on the fields provided by the child class. This validation will be common across all the child classes.

Comment: Does the root validator need to be `pre=True`? Omitting that kwarg from the root validator decorator, and using `print(values.get('description'))` should print out "foo" when instantiating `SubClass()`.

Comment: @cstoltze I need `pre=True` because I'm initializing some other attributes. Removing `pre=True` does cause `description` to be accessible, but then the other attributes I was initializing throw a `field required (type=value_error.missing)` error

Comment: Maybe split it into two separate methods? A `pre=True` for the initialization of the other attributes, and another root validator that is not `pre` for the description validation.

Comment: The initialization of the other attributes depends on the `description` attribute, unfortunately...

Comment: Is `description` even supposed to be a regular model field? Or is it supposed to be specifically just a class attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, sorry - its a class attribute (IE, the same for all instances of the class. eg all SubClass instances should have the description as `foo`)

Comment: In Pydantic the "normal" way to define model fields is via `name: type` annotations in the class namespace. Those will not become as class attributes, but special instance attributes on instances of that model. This is why I asked what the purpose of `description` should be. From your last comment I gather that it is supposed to be an actual **class attribute**, thus the same for all instances of that class. I'll write an answer for you with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a [**`ClassVar`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) annotation for `description`.

With Pydantic models, simply adding a `name: type` or `name: type = value` in the class namespace will create a **field** on that model, not a class attribute. If you are interested, I explained in a bit more detail how Pydantic fields are different from regular attributes in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712642). (The topic there is private attributes, but the explanation is still relevant.)

You want `description` to be **class attribute**, i.e. not a field of the model that can be assigned different values on different instances. The section on [automatically excluded attributes](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes) of the Pydantic docs say: (emphasis mine)

> Class variables which begin with an underscore and **attributes annotated with `typing.ClassVar` will be automatically excluded from the model**.

So to achieve what you want, you need to explicitly tell the model that `description` is supposed to be a `ClassVar`, not a normal field:

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class BaseClass(BaseModel):
    description: ClassVar[str]  # not a field
    spam: str
    eggs: int

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def initialize(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if cls.description == "foo":
            values["spam"] = values["spam"].upper()
            values["eggs"] = values["eggs"] ** 2
        return values


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    description = "foo"


instance = SubClass(spam="abc", eggs=2)
print(instance.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "spam": "ABC",
    "eggs": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error because `cls` inside the `root_validator` is referring to the class object itself, you cannot access it directly from cls because `description` is an attribute of instances of `SubClass`.

You can access the class attributes in the initialize root validator via the values dictionary

Also you gonna need to remove `pre=True` because it processes the validator before the model initialization.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from typing import Dict, Any

class BaseClass(BaseModel):
    description: str

    @root_validator
    def initialize(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        print(values.get("description")) 
        return values

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    description = "foo"

SubClass()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong - unfortunately I need to use `pre=True` because I'm initializing some other attributes (code omitted in OP) based on the values provided by the child class. If I remove it, I get `field required (type=value_error.missing)` errors.

Answer (score 0):

To access the description attribute from the child classes, you can use the **class** attribute, which refers to the class object itself. The "initialize" method is a class-level method meaning that is cannot access attributes of the instance or the class. You can try using:

```
print(cls.__dict__.get("description"))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the value is `None`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712642/) for _why_ that does not work.