# FastAPI _id not in request body

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

FastAPI not getting or sending `_id` field in request body even though its described in the Models.

Why is that? Do I need to change it to an `id` field to handle?

Removing the Model the API has to return will result in getting those _id-s even if the controller still described to return that Model

Source:

```
MODELS:
class EmailBaseModel(BaseModel):
    title: str
    group: str
    template: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "title": "Foo",
                "group": "Bar",
                "template": "<html></html>",
            }
        }

class EmailUpdateRequestModel(EmailBaseModel):
    _id: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "_id": "123-abc-456-efg",
                "title": "Foo",
                "group": "Bar",
                "template": "<html></html>",
            }
        }


class EmailResponseModel(EmailBaseModel):
    _id: str
    # created_at: datetime | None = None
    # updated_at: datetime | None = None

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "_id": "123-abc-456-efg",
                "title": "Foo",
                "group": "Bar",
                "template": "<html></html>",
                # "created_at": "2023/01/01",
                # "updated_at": "2023/01/02",
            }
        }

ROUTER:
@email_router.patch('/')
async def update_email(response: Response, email: EmailUpdateRequestModel, token: str = Depends(token_auth_scheme)) -> EmailResponseModel:
    return update_email_controller(response=response, email=email, token=token)

ROUTE CONTROLLER:
def update_email_controller(response: Response, email: EmailUpdateRequestModel, token: str) -> EmailResponseModel:
    print(email)
    auth_result = VerifyToken(token.credentials).verify()

    if auth_result.get("status"):
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        return auth_result

    newEmail = {"$set": {
        "title": email.title,
        "group": email.group,
        "template": email.template,
    }}

    result: EmailModel = emailCollection.find_one_and_update({
        '_id': ObjectId(email._id)},
        newEmail,
        return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER
    )

    if result == None:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        return {"message": "Email not found"}

    response.status_code = status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
    return emailResponseEntity(result)

serialiser:

def emailResponseEntity(email) -> dict:
    return {
        "_id": str(email["_id"]),
        "title": str(email["title"]),
        "group": str(email["group"]),
        "template": str(email["template"]),
        # "created_at": email["created_at"],
        # "updated_at": email["updated_at"]
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code, so that we can help you

Comment: Added. Hope I have provided all that is needed.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709118) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_id` field can not be read from the object because any `_attr` or `__attr` will be treated as a protected and private attribute of a class and can not be accessed from the object.

If you want to have the `_id` field be a part of the request as `_id` you can write something like this:

```py
id: str = Field(..., alias="_id")
```

then you can access the field like this:

```py
email.id
```

but in the body, it still will be `_id`.

Additional note:

- If you want to get the `dict` of the object model like `_id` - you can do something like this:

  ```py
  email.dict(by_alias=True)
  ```

  This will use the aliases as keys (by default if the field has no alias -  it will use the field attribute name.

Comment: I have posted my solution but have tried yours and works as well. I gonna flag this as a solution for the credit of your help. If I were to google this this is the answer I would expect.

Answer (score -1):

Heres my solution:

- Removed the enforced model response from API as subroutines are already enforced to return a specific Model. => Responses now returns `_id` with the body
- For updating an object I moved the `_id` param from the request body to a separate `_id` parameter that is now interpreted by FastApi to the request query

As a side effect not where is 1 Model less to maintain (removed EmailUpdateReqestModel as now only EmailRequestModel is requred)