# pydantic error when adding a field to a derived class: ValueError: "SubDerived" object has no field "_myVar"

Tags: python, pydantic

Ran into an issue trying to add a field to a Derived class, which seems due to pydantic 1.10.12 (as it works fine with the latest pydantic). Here is a minimal repro:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Base():
    pass


class Derived(Base, BaseModel):

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        print("Derived.__init__() called")
        self._myVar = True

    @property
    def myVar(self):
        return self._myVar

    @myVar.setter
    def myVar(self, value):
        self._myVar = value


class SubDerived(Derived):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = SubDerived()
    print(v.myVar)
```

If I try pydantic 1.10.12, which my real project dependencies require, I get this exception:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
"SubDerived" object has no field "_myVar"
  File "/Users/rah/repos/pythonTests/inheritanceTest.py", line 13, in __init__
    self._myVar = True
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/rah/repos/pythonTests/inheritanceTest.py", line 29, in <module> (Current frame)
    v = SubDerived()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: "SubDerived" object has no field "_myVar"
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  I tried to override `__init__` and set `self._myVar` in each inheriting class, but I get the same exception, and as far as I know I shouldn't have to do that anyways.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712642/19770795) may be of interest to you to explain, why you got that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you got that error, I suggest you check out my answer to this question:

[How are attribute names with underscore managed in Pydantic Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709118)

---

From the way you constructed your example it seems very clear that this attribute is not supposed to be an actual model field, but rather some special protected attribute with a property interface.

If that is the case, the solution is to simply define it as a [`PrivateAttr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#private-model-attributes) like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr


class Base:
    pass


class Derived(Base, BaseModel):
    _my_var: bool = PrivateAttr(True)

    def __init__(self, **data: object) -> None:
        super().__init__(**data)
        print("Derived.__init__() called")

    @property
    def my_var(self) -> bool:
        return self._my_var


class SubDerived(Derived):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = SubDerived()
    print(v.my_var)
```

**Note**: Pydantic v1 does not allow property setters at all, as you can see from [this issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1577). Pydantic v2 has [computed fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.1/usage/computed_fields/) for this purpose.

If you want to be able able to cleanly set that protected attribute in v1, you will have to write a regular setter method or use one of the workarounds shown in that issue I linked, which all involve some override of `BaseModel.__setattr__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add fields to a pydantic class after initialization i.e. after calling `super().__init__(**data)`. Why not simply using pydantic as it's intended?

```py
class Derived(Base, BaseModel):
    _myVar: bool = True

    @property
    def myVar(self):
        return self._myVar

    @myVar.setter
    def myVar(self, value):
        self._myVar = value
```

Alternatively, you could use something hacky like `object.__setattr__(self, "_myVar", True)` or adding it to `data` before calling the superclass constructor. But in your example there is no need for that.

Comment: That doesn't work; I get the same exception, but I did figure out a fix.

Comment: Well, I tested that snippet with the version you mentioned and on my machine it worked as intended without an error. Did you test the snippet or your bigger code?

Comment: Anyways, your proposed solution is of course the "pydantic" way to do it. Just assumed you have some complex logic and were in the need to use `@property` there.

Comment: This is fine, if you want `_myVar` to be a field. Just beware that the property setter **will always fail** in Pydantic v1. See [this issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1577).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the code like this to get it working:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Base():
    pass


class Derived(Base, BaseModel):
    myVar: bool = Field(default_factory=lambda: True)


class SubDerived(Derived):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = SubDerived()
    v.myVar = False
    print(v.myVar)
```

Note, I am using the `Field(default_factory=lambda: True)` because in my real code I am calling an external property to set the value.  In this sample, `myVar: bool = True` also works, but I needed to test calling an external prop.

Comment: Note that this is fundamentally different from your initial code in that now `myVar` here is an actual model field, whereas before it was not. If you are OK with that, this is fine of course, it just seemed like you wanted it to be something special (i.e. not a field) from the code you showed in your question.