# Subclassing pydantic model with private class attributes

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have a use case where it is desirable to pre-load some data singletons onto pydantic models. I'd like to do this in as DRY a way as possible, so carefully loading that data in the right base classes like this:

```py
import typing
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    parent_data: typing.ClassVar = {}


class Child(Parent):
    _child_data = typing.ClassVar = {}
```

When `Parent.parent_data` is public like this, it throws an error:

```
NameError: Field name "parent_data" shadows an attribute in parent "Parent"; you might want to use a different field name with "alias='parent_data'".
```

This error does not happen if it is instead `Parent._parent_data`. Is there some underlying pydantic philosophy on how class attributes and private variables work on pydantic? Why can't `Parent.parent_data` be public?

Comment: Typo. You are assigning an empty dictionary to `typing.ClassVar`, which completely breaks the Pydantic machinery (and much more presumably). It should be `_child_data: ClassVar = {}` (notice the colon).

Comment: But if you are interested in a few details about private attributes in Pydantic, you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709118). In short: Without the underscore, it becomes an actual model **field**. Those are treated very differently than normal attributes in Pydantic.